# Set OnAutomaticHitTest and OnInteractiveHitTest during runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm placing my Plane Stage and Plane Finder and setting the attributes at runtime, but there are two attributes I can't figure out how to set:  `OnAutomaticHitTest` and `OnInteractiveHitTest`.

I saw that it expects something of the type `HitTestEvent`, but i can't figure out how to set my custom function here.

Can someone Help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the documentation for the `PlaneFinderBehaviour` [here](https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/reference/unity/classVuforia_1_1PlaneFinderBehaviour.html)

Essentially, you don't actually define these attribute but you use them to fire events.

**For example:**

```
public class CustomPlaneFinderBehaviour : PlaneFinderBehaviour
{
    public void CustomIntPerformHitTest(Vector2 screenPosition)
    {
        //Triggered on interactive hit test
    }
    public void CustomAutoPerformHitTest(Vector2 screenPosition)
    {
        //Triggered on automatic hit test
    }
}
```

Then in the **inspector you are able to define the events**, by pressing the plus button and choosing the current script in the box. It then gives you the option to change the function that is called.

*Here on interactive hit test has been defined and automatic hit test has not:*

[image]

Comment: Can you set them programmatically, do you need to do it in the inspector?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Unity's AddListener call

```
void HandleHitTest(HitTestResult htr)
{
    //Handle Test Here
}

planeFinderBehavior.OnAutomaticHitTest.AddListener(HandleHitTest);
```